# Looking for Amp connector family name for connector similar to Molex Mini-Fit Jr

Tags: connector

I recall having used a connector family from Amp (now TE) that is very similar to the Molex Mini-Fit Jr family.  These connectors are NOT interchangeable.  The Amp connector has round pins, the Mini-Fit Jr connector has square pins.  However, the body styling is very similar, both in size and polarization keying.

I've been searching but can't seem to find that family.  Can anyone tell me the family name or typical part number?

Answer (score 1):

That's a big family.

Connectors like the Mini-Fit could be classified as follow;

### Power Connectors  4.20 mm pitch up to 13A

**Rectangular: Single, Dual Row, other, Wire-to-Board, Wire-to-Wire, Cable-to-Cable**

- Terminal
- Receptacle
- Plug  , Cap  ,
- Housing (HSG)
- Header

  - Locking, Double Lock, Triple Lock
  - std temp, high temp
- Pitch: 3.3, 5, 6, 6.5, 6.6, 7.92, 9 mm
- etc did not find much

But Search for 4.2mm found :
**Mate-N-Lok**, Val-U-Lok

https://www.te.com/usa-en/search.html?q=mate-N-lok&source=header